# bootstrap vue toast disappears immediately

Tags: vue.js, toast, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to display a message using toast. So I tried all example code on (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/toasts/) here,
but when I click the button to show up toast, it showed once and disappear immediately.

I tried `this.$bvToast.toast` to `this.$root.$bvToast.toast`
and `import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'`

but it doesn't work..

here is my code

```
<template>
 <div>
    <b-button @click="makeToast()">Show Toast</b-button>
    <b-button @click="makeToast(true)">Show Toast (appended)</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        toastCount: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      makeToast(append = false) {
        this.toastCount++
        this.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast number ${this.toastCount}`, {
          title: 'BootstrapVue Toast',
          autoHideDelay: 5000,
        // 'no-auto-hide':true,
          appendToast: append
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

exactly same the example code..

I'm using this version

```
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
```

How can I fix this?? Help me..

Comment: does it still hides if u uncheck comment // no-auto-hide: true?

Comment: @coure2011 the "no-auto-hide" is actually using the html syntax for the property, it should be "noAutoHide: true" when calling the toast  function inside a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your code with bootstrap v4 and it works perfectly. I think you are using boostrap v5 but it's not compatible with vue-bootstrap version 2.21.2. So try to downgrade bootstrap version of your project.

Please see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-matan-6ohmd).

Comment: Thanks to answer! I downgrade bootstrap version to v4, it works!

Answer (score 5):

Add this to CSS for Bootstrap 5:

```
.toast:not(.show) {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Worked, though I had to apply this to my global css file, it didn't work when adding this to the component i'm triggering the toast from.

Comment: Yep, I think it has something to do with scope vs non-scoped styles (but ain’t sure). Anyway, this seems like a global-worthy CSS, given that you might have toasts in other components as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade ur bootstrap-vue version to 4.6. have a good one.
Modify to package.json and after use the next command.

```
npm i
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).